# Ribbon Bar - Disable Save - Enable Edit

Tags: ribbon

I'm using an infopath browser enabled form in our sharepoint 2010 list. Is there a way to systematically or programmatically hide or disable certain buttons of my choosing in the ribbon bar? I would like to disable/hide the save button in edit mode and push them to the infopath forms submit buttons instead, however, I would like to let the user edit the form if it comes up in display mode. Any direction would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call some javascript using this method:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2005/06/17/430347.aspx

The script to call would be like this (edit to fit the button(s) you want to remove):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function HideDeleteOption() 
    {
        try {
document.getElementById("Ribbon.ContextualTabs.InfoPathListDisplayTab.Manage.Controls.btnDelete-Medium").style.display = "none";
        }
        catch (ex) 
        {
        }
    }

    function HideEditDeleteOption() 
    {
        try {                
  document.getElementById("Ribbon.ContextualTabs.InfoPathListTab.Actions").style.display = "none"
        }
        catch (ex) 
        {
        }
    }

    setTimeout("HideDeleteOption();", 100);
    setTimeout("HideEditDeleteOption();", 100);
```